# How to redirect more than one links

Tags: php, html, redirect

I need to redirect some of my html pages to corresponding php pages.

That means if a user comes from any referring site to my www.example.com/sample.html page, he should be redirected to the www.example.com/sample.php page without showing the html page.

I need to do this for 3 pages. How can I do this ? Please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .htaccess file for redirecting you file properly with

include cose in .htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php

or in other way

use php like

echo "window.location='\www.example.com/sample.php'\";

Hope i will help you in better way

Comment: RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php

Comment: Of course, this works only if the name of the html page and the php page are the same. The elegant solution for lower latency and search engines sake, I prefer the "Redirect 301 ^(.*).html$ $1.php"

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `.htaccess` file and put it in the root of your web server. It should contain the following:

```
Redirect 301 /sample1.html http://www.example.com/sample1.php
Redirect 301 /sample2.html http://www.example.com/sample2.php
Redirect 301 /sample3.html http://www.example.com/sample3.php
```

Comment: In which root I should place this file ?

Comment: The one for the site hosting the .html files you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess with the following line:

Redirect 301 ^(.*).html$ $1.php

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
<?php
header('Location: www.example.com/sample.php');
?>
```

Comment: I need to do that for .html file :(

Comment: Add this line in your html file.It will redirect the page after 1 second <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://www.redirect-location.com">

Comment: I don't wanna show the .html page there and then redirect. Is there any option through .htaccess